# How to delimit the range of an instance variable of a class in java?

Tags: java

I am doing some java exercise and trying to figure out a way to impose restrictions on the scope of an instance variable.

For example I constructed a class called Time. It has 3 instance variables, hour, minute and second.

Take hour for example, it should be between 0 to 23. I have some methods inside this class to manipulate the hour variable. But I need to make sure hour is always within 0 to 23.

I know there is a method, enum type. Like this

```
public enum hour {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23
}
```

and then insert an hour type variable in Time class.

But what if hour is a double type variable, continuous variable. And it has its upper and lower limit. How do i delimit a continuous variable?

Comment: An hour should not be a double type variable. The value that is not stored as a whole in an hour is stored a minutes, and then to seconds, then milliseconds, so on. Now, tell us, why are you doing this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no compiler save way to set limits. a possible (and always recommended) way is that you use a private variable and check in the setter method the bounds and throw a RuntimeException if the bounds are not correct.

Example:

```
public class Time {
    private double hour;

    public void setHour(double hour) {
        if(hour < 0 ) { // and so on - i think you can imagine the logical expression
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour "+hour+" is not valid.");
        }
        this.hour = hour;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sorontur, you are right and I know the error raising method. It is just if I have multiple methods that manipulate Time in the class, then I need to throw the exception in every method. I was kind of impatient. Now I know exception handling is the best way and it's a good coding habit, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bean validators](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html)

```
public class Time {

@Min(0) @Max(23)
private int hour;

public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi yeforriak, thank you for the advice. Bean validators seems to be a powerful tool. But I am not running Java EE. Can I use it in Eclipse Standard?

Comment: @FriedrichPei you can use JSR-303 on Java SE, http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303

Comment: I found an example here http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (some would even say this is the correct way) to model `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second` as types, and apply proper range checking in each type.

```
class Hour {
   final int val;

   Hour(int val) {
       if (val < 0 || val > 23) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Out of range [0...23]: " + val);
       }
       this.val = val;
   }

   // ...
}
```